# How to get WebElement in ItestListener

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, listener

I want to get the `WebElement` in `ITestListener` class on `TestFailure` Method.

Is there any way to get the `WebElement` in `ItestListener` on `testfailure` method?

I have tried to get the `testclass` name and `testmethod` name and it worked but how to get `WebElement`:

```
// WebElement inputbox i need this in ItestListener
public void test1() {
  String title = driver.getTitle();
  String etitle = "Google1";
  WebElement inputbox = driver.findElement(By.id("fakebox-input1"));
  inputbox.click();
  Assert.assertEquals(title, etitle);
}
// my Listener class 
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
  System.out.println("Test failed >.......");
  String classname = iTestResult.getInstanceName(); // class name
  this.driver = demo.driver;
  System.out.println(iTestResult.getName()); // test method name
  CaptureScreenShot cs = new CaptureScreenShot();
  cs.takescreenshotoferror(iTestResult.getName(), driver);
}
```

I can get the class name and method name on `testfailure`, using this:

```
get
webelement
```

Comment: How we get the class name bu using iTestResult.getInstanceName(); is there any mehtod or any other way to get it.

Comment: I just want to take the screenshot of the webelement which gets failed, so that to pass the webelement parameter in CaptureScreenShot method takescreenshotoferror();

Comment: How do you get the driver instance in your onTestFailure method i.e. demo.driver ?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the class where your driver is initialized in your ITestListener.

I would suggest that you create a separate Listener class which will extend your Base Class(where driver is initialized) and implement ITestListener.

Something like this:

```
 public class ReportListener extends BaseClass implements ITestListener
```

My driver is initalized in `BaseClass`, so I can use my driver object to take screenshot or perform any other operations.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that I thought I should call out:

Failures are of two types in WebDriver (apart from the failures related to loading the browser by itself) when it comes to elements.

1. Not being able to find a particular element.
2. Not being able to do some operation on an element after it was successfully found.

So not all failures would have a WebElement associated with themselves. 
Once you do get a WebElement, there's not much that you can do with it (taking screenshot is good, but what good is that screenshot going to do, when it doesnt have any info on the page where it occurred)

All said and done, to accomplish what you are after, you need the following:

1. An implementation that is build by extending `org.openqa.selenium.support.events.AbstractWebDriverEventListener` or by implementing the interface `org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener`
2. A test code that makes use of `org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver`

   3. A TestNG listener that implements `org.testng.ITestListener` to track failures as and when they happen.

Here's a sample that shows all of this in action

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.AbstractWebDriverEventListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;

public class LocalEventListener extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener {

  @Override
  public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    ITestResult result = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    result.setAttribute("CurrentElement", element);
  }
}
```

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestNGLocalListener implements ITestListener {

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    Object object = result.getAttribute("CurrentElement");
    if (object == null) {
      return;
    }

    WebElement element = (WebElement) object;
    System.err.println("The element that caused the failure is " + element.toString());
  }
}
```

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(TestNGLocalListener.class)
public class SampleTestClass {
  private EventFiringWebDriver driver;

  @BeforeClass
  public void setup() {
    driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());
    driver.register(new LocalEventListener());
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/checkboxes");
    WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
    driver.executeScript("arguments[0].blah.blah", checkbox);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void cleanup() {
    if (driver != null) {
      driver.quit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you will try this hope it will help.